# “Мне бы на юг.” Где здесь сказуемое?

Tags: грамматика

Правильно ли я понимаю, что от сказуемого в этом предложении осталась только частица "бы"?

Comment: Вы так спрашиваете как будто сумели найти тут подлежащее :)

Comment: Забавно кстати - предложение из двух дополнений и частицы...

Comment: За кадром сказуемое, так бывает

Comment: Отсутствие подлежащего меня, если честно, не сильно смущает. Непонятно другое: если добавить в предложение, казалось бы, пропущенный глагол 'поехать', то в состав сказуемого вошла бы частица 'бы' (во всяком случае, в найденных мною в сети справочниках 'бы' всегда включают в состав сказуемого). А в этом предложении к чему относится 'бы'?

Comment: *Бы* всегда относится к глаголу (в данном случае к тому, который подразумевается), даже если он опущен.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Эллиптические предложения — особый вид неполных предложений. В них всегда отсутствует глагол-сказуемое. Отличаются тем, что они понятны без контекста и без ситуации.В данном случае предложение безличное.Опущен глагол движения в форме инфинитива. Похожий пример :Мне в Париж, по делу.

Answer (score 3):

Хочется классифицировать как неполное инфинитивное предложение (*Мне бы [поехать] на юг* (сказуемое - да, пропущено). Но обоснований найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить альтернативную интерпретацию.

Глагольная часть сказуемого в этом эллиптическом предложении — **было бы**. Кроме неё в этом предложении опущены также подлежащее **поехать** (или другой, соответствующий контексту, глагол движения, например, **уехать**, **слетать**, **податься**, и т. д.), а также именная часть составного именного сказуемого, **хорошо**. Таким образом, если восстановить все его члены, это предложение выглядело бы так:

> Мне [было] бы [хорошо] [поехать] на юг.

Здесь:

- **[поехать] на юг** — подлежащее, выраженное инфинитивным оборотом,
- **[было] бы [хорошо]** — составное именное сказуемое, состоящее из связки **быть** в условном наклонении и именной части, выраженной наречием **хорошо**,
- **мне** — косвенное дополнение.